# Using multiple filters in Google App Engine Query

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to execute a query in `App Engine`, the sql version of this select query would look like this

```
"WHERE (personId ="+personId+" AND uploadedDate >"+lastCheckDate+") OR ("+personId ="+personId+" AND updatedDate >"+lastCheckDate+")"
```

in my app engine backend I create multiple filters and use `CompositeFilterOperator` to combine the filters like this using `Objectify`

```
Filter f1 = new FilterPredicate("personId", FilterOperator.EQUAL,personId);
Filter f2 = new FilterPredicate("uploadDate", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN,lastCheckDate);
Filter f3 = new FilterPredicate("updatedDate", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN,lastCheckDate);

Filter final1 = CompositeFilterOperator.and(f1,f2);
Filter final2 = CompositeFilterOperator.and(f1,f3);

Filter qFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.or(final1,final2);
Query<CloudRecord> query = ofy().load().type(CloudRecord.class).filter(qFilter).limit(limit);
```

but I get this error when I call it in my android app

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
 {
   "code": 503,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "global",
       "message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"CloudRecord\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"personId\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"uploadDate\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n",
       "reason": "backendError"
     }
   ],
   "message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"CloudRecord\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"personId\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"uploadDate\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n"
 }
```

All those fields are indexed in the class

```
@Entity public class CloudRecord {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Index
    long uploadDate;
    @Index
    long updatedDate;
    @Index
    String personId;
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I know it is a problem with the filters because if I comment them out the query executes fine. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you re- read of the doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig  - what is not clear about ` You specify configuration for datastore indexes in WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml, in your app's war/ directory. `  Secondly you should also read about about the limitations around in-equality filters.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Restrictions_on_queries  - Even once you create the indexes you can only have you will note is says `a single query may not use inequality comparisons on more than one property`

Answer (score 2):

GAE has two kinds of indexes: Single-property indexes, which you declare with `@Index` and get created when you save the entity, and multi-property indexes, which are defined in datastore-indexes.xml (or yml) and are built automatically. You're issuing a query that requires a multi-property index. More documentation can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig

Note that in order for a specific entity instance to participate in a multiproperty index, it must be saved with the relevant individual fields indexed.

Comment: I just read through the documentation linked and I still dont understand what I have to do, I dont have a file `datastore-indexes.xml` in my project and if its auto generated then how can I change it? Do you have a link to an example or something?

Comment: Create the file in your WEB-INF directory. Unfortunately I don't have any better links.